# JQuery FadeIn/Out Only Works One Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a very simply div that uses JQuery to fade in when the mouse hovers over the div. Then when the mouse leaves the div it fades back out.

**My Problem:** The fade in/out only works once. When I place my mouse over the div the second time it doesn't fade in.

Whats going wrong? JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hWyUn/3/

```
<div id="test" style="opacity: 0; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;">
</div>

$("#test").mouseenter(function()
                    {
                        $(this).css("opacity","1").fadeIn();
                    });

$("#test").mouseleave(function()
                    {
                        $(this).fadeOut();
                    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using fadeTo Worked for me:

```
$("#test").mouseenter(function()
    {
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
    });

$("#test").mouseleave(function()
    {
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0);
    });
```

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/hWyUn/4/

Answer (score 3):

See the jQuery docs. fadeOut() will set the display property to none once it finishes. Effectively removing it from your page.

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Answer (score 1):

It will work only if element is hidden.
You can set the element's display to none by doing $(element).css('display', 'none') before $(element).fadeIn() :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your problem. 
Check out the fiddle...

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hWyUn/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You could always try using the the jQuery's Animate to animate the opacity, instead of fading in and out. Might be shorter code.

Animating the opacity will not set the display to none, so you can still fiddle around with it after it is faded out.

[See my jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nR2Pu/)